# CSS class added via JS to stay during browser session

Tags: javascript, css

Now this added class by onclick is removed after site refresh or when going into subpage. What line is neccessary in my script to have this class remained active during browser session ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('box').setAttribute("class", "contrast");

}
  </script>
```

Comment: Please try rephrasing the question and show significant part of the code in order to understand the problem

Comment: (Like menu on header which one should active) 
When you are going to next page and you got the refreshed page then you should persist which link was active. It may be maintained by API or url.

Comment: @pinturic I think he/she is wondering why some classes/elements, which were added though JS were removed after page reload. I already posted the answer about `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 2):

When you add some classes or elements to your page with JS, it will disappear when you refresh the page, or close/reopen it. It's normal behaviour.

To store information for a longer periods of time, you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`:

- `sessionStorage.setItem` will be cleared only when you close the browser, and
- `localStorage.setItem` will store information "forever".

Here is introduction articles:

- [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
- [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

To store some information, use this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

Then, when your page is loading, you can read stored value and add appropriate class:

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
if (data) {
    document.querySelector(yourselector).className = 'yourclass';
}
```